# Launch an event when phone screen is unlocked with a fingerprint (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, ios, fingerprint, lockscreen

I would like to create an app both for Android and iPhone that perform certain actions when phone is unlocked with fingerprint. Furthermore I would like the app to perform different actions depending on which finger was used to unlock.
Is something like this possible already?

Comment: iOS doesn't give any indication about which finger was used for local authentication.

Comment: Neither does Android, unless you plan to rely on hidden APIs which may break at any point.

Answer (score 0):

**Iphone:-** If the application is open then phone is unlocked then you can get the unlock event of the phone but if the app is closed then there is no way in iphone to get unlock event.

**Android Solution:-**
Register a Broadcast receiver that handles the action "ACTION_USER_PRESENT". Have a look at this link for more detail https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT

```
public class LockStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
      // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: So is this possible or not?

Comment: I am not just trying to get an unlock event. I need to know whether its fingerprint unlock and which finger was used.